# How to add a sidebar in a cakephp layout, from zero?

Tags: html, css, cakephp, layout, sidebar

I'm working on Cake 2.7.5, but I'm really new at this.

I need to create an static sidebar in my cakephp layout for displaying user's menu actions. (There is no difference in menu's content between Admins and standard users). 
At the start, I only put the menu options at page header displayed "inline", but now I have too many options and no more space available, this is because I need to put them displayed in left side of the layout as a list.

I think I only need to add code in my `default.ctp` layout, but, I don't know what HTML elements and CSS classes must create. I suppose `cake.generic.css` contains the selectors for the tags that I need.

Any idea will be welcome, Thanks (Sorry for my limited English).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code inside your layout

```
<style>
.leftMenu{
    width:30%;
    float:left;
}
.leftMenu ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
</style>
<div class="leftMenu">
<ul>
  <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

or you can put this code inside element and call element

```
<?php echo $this->element('sidebar');?>
```

Comment: thanks, It works, where I should create an element??